# Positioning custom widget in tkinter

Tags: python, class, tkinter, indexing

I'm trying to position multiple instances of a custom widget in a window, with the goal of the user moving items from the `Listbox` of one widget to that of another.

My widget class:

```
import tkinter as tk

class DistriBox(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, name):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=name, anchor="center")
        self.label.grid(column=0, row=0)
        self.lb_locs = tk.Listbox(self, width=15, height=5)
        self.lb_locs.grid(column=0, row=1)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.lb_locs.size()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print('entering __setitem__ with %4d and %s' % (key, value))
        items_already = self.lb_locs.size()
        self.lb_locs.insert(items_already, value)
```

and the application:

```
import tkinter as tk
import DistriBox as db

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        group1 = []
        for i in range(0,3):
            group1.append(db.DistriBox(self, 'group 1'))
            group1[i].grid(column=0, row=i)

        group1[0] = 'California'
        group1[1] = 'Utah'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('650x600')
    App(root).grid(column=0, row=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

Problems:

- Only 3 widgets are drawn whereas the loop specifies four.
- I'm unable to insert items into a specific widget's `Listbox`.

Comment: Are you aware that `range(0,3)` returns 0, 1, and 2 but _not_ 3?

Answer (score 0):

As @Bryan Oakley mentioned in a comment, you're not using [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) properly if you want four widgets (it's also not necessary to specify the starting value when it's zero). Admittedly the documentation is pretty vague, so I understand your confusion.

As for why items are not being inserted, it's because you're not referencing the instances of your `DistriBox` widget properly — `group1` is a list of them, so to reference one of them and call its `__setitem__()` method, you need to have *two* levels of indices as shown below. Note I also changed the `name` of each custom widget to make it easier to tell them apart.

```
import tkinter as tk
import DistriBox as db

class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        group1 = []
        for i in range(4):  # CHANGED.
            group1.append(db.DistriBox(self, f'group {i}'))  # CHANGED.
            group1[i].grid(column=0, row=i)

        group1[0][0] = 'California'  # FIXED INDEXING.
        group1[0][1] = 'Utah'        # FIXED INDEXING.

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('650x600')
    App(root).grid(column=0, row=0)
    root.mainloop()
```